# Error in my next button in second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason, the buttons on the second view controller are not working. When I test the code on my device, its giving me this error:
Thread 1: "-[DepressionApp1.SecondViewController NextButton]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103605560"

Can someone find the error?

Here is the code for my second view controller

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func nextButton(){
       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "third") as! ThirdViewController
          vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
          present(vc,animated: true)
      }
    
    @IBAction func prevbutton(){
    
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "") as! ViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(vc,animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is the code for my first view controller

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func Btnimagepicker(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.allowsEditing=true
        picker.delegate=self
        present(picker, animated:true)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image=info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {return}
        imageview.image=image
        dismiss(animated:true)
    
    }
    @IBAction func didTapButton(){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second") as! SecondViewController
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc,animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here is the code for my third view controller

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBOutlet weak var Text: UITextView!
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

     @IBOutlet weak var Text: UITextView!
     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Basically, the first view controller is supposed to let the user pick an image and go to the next view controller. Than in the second view controller, the user should be able to go back to the first view controller, or go the third view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your  @IBOutlet is correctly connected to the nib. Most of the times I encountered such an error was due to miss connection or an old connection that was not removed. If you will upload a link to a project with this issue it will be easy to find and fix

Comment: I figured out there were actually 2 classes connected to the button. I removed the fake one but now its giving me this error:Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 (1)

Comment: I wish I could help more. But without a minimal reproducible example it is kind of hard